# My usb got corrupted? I cant do anything with usb

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I think my usb is corrupted or something. I used it for rufus but after that every software is crashing (when i use the usb on the software). The explorer is waiting me and after 5 minutes it says: "Windows cannot access the disk" How do i fix my usb??

EDIT: I tried checkdisk too. It said The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.

Comment: You should try formatting it and then, if successful, check for errors.

Comment: When i go to disk management (tried in other diskk tools too). It says "Connecting to Virtual Disk Service" but when i unplug the usb it loads instantly and twhen i try to format it doesnt work.

Comment: Then it's probably defective.

Comment: also when i try to dlete parition it doesnt work. the usb disconnects (it is plugged and it was working with no issues before)

Comment: Everything fails at some point. The intense writing operation with Rufus may have triggered the failure for a drive that was in its last legs already.

Comment: I tried with arch linux before and it work. but i tried the tool named "ventoy" but it did fail and my files were getting corrupted or something